# How to convert Binary to Strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, encoding, binary

I am currently working on a binary encryption code: [Sender(Msg Input=> Binary Conversion)] : [Receiver (Binary Conversion => Msg Output)]

As of now I am able to convert text based Msgs , e.g) How are you? etc.

```
print("Enter Msg:")
def Binary_Encryption(message):
    message = ''.join(format(i, 'b') for i in bytearray(message, encoding ='utf-8'))
    print(message)
Binary_Encryption(input("").replace (" ","\\"))
```

*Output: 10010001101111111011110111001100001111001011001011011100111100111011111110101111111*

After the binary string is obtained, by just copying the string and placing it within this block of code will decrypt it.

```
def Binary_Decryption(binary):
    string = int(binary, 2)
    return string

bin_data = (input("Enter Binary:\n"))
str_data =''

for i in range(0, len(bin_data), 7):

    temp_data = bin_data[i:i + 7]

    decimal_data = Binary_Decryption(temp_data)

    str_data = str_data + chr(decimal_data)

print("Decrypted Text:\n"+str_data.replace("\\"," "))
```

*Output: How are you?*

But I am not able to convert a certain inputs , e.g) ?? , 8879 , Oh! How are You? etc.
basically the msgs that are not being converted are Msgs with multiple uses of numbers or special
characters.
Msg Input for **??** gives **"⌂▼"** and **8879** gives **"qc?☺"** while **Oh! How are You?** gives **"OhC9◄_o9CeK93_k▼**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the special characters (!, ?) contains only 6 bits, while the other characters 7.This messes things up if there are other characters behind the special one I think. Maybe something like this should work. There is probably a better way to solve this though.

```
def Binary_Encryption(message):
    s = ""
    for i in bytearray(message, encoding="utf-8"):
        c = format(i, "b")  
        addon = 7 - len(c) 
        c = addon * "0" + c  # prepend 0 if len shorter than 7
        s += c  # Add to string

    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are copying the output from `binary_encrypt` directly which truncate leading zeros so `8` instead of being `00111000` it became `111000` which result in `2` bits being used from next ASCII binary character since ASCII characters are represented as 8-bits values to print number `8897` use`0011100000111000001110010011011100001010` as input to `binary_decrypt`. look for ASCII table to see the binary equivalents for each character.Just edit your code like this.

```
print("Enter Msg:")
def Binary_Encryption(message):
# pass 08b to format
    message = ''.join(format(i, '08b') for i in bytearray(message, encoding ='utf-8'))
    print(message)
Binary_Encryption(input("").replace (" ","\\"))
```